# Find a Text Criteria in a Column and then adding a border to the entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Table.  In Column C, I need to find the Name "Homemade".  And then I need to add a border to that entire Row.
I'm following the prompts, but the error says `Expected: =`.  I can't figure out where I'm missing the =

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Ws

Dim Homemade As Range

'Find "Homemade" in Column C
Set Homemade = .Range("C:C").Find("HOMEMADE", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

'Add Border to Entire Row
With Homemade
.EntireRow.BorderAround (, xlThick, ,vbgreen)
End With

End with
Next Ws
```

Comment: The parentheses in `(, xlThick, ,vbgreen)` are the problem. Drop them (Parentheses bite again!!)

Comment: [good info about using parentheses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-parentheses-in-code) in that link from MS documentation.

Comment: There's more commentary about why you shouldn't have parentheses in the linked duplicate (and the MS documentation link provided in comments is also helpful).

Comment: Grrr.. On the Pop line that shows the parameters, there were parentheses!  OK so, I took off the parentheses, but the Color did not change on the border.